Summation of reciprocals of prime powers of 2
I could not find an answer to the following: sum of reciprocals of prime powers of $2$:in other words $\frac{1}{(2^2)} + \frac{1}{(2^3)} + \frac{1}{(2^5)} + \frac{1}{(2^7)} +\dots$

@YvesDaoust - False prime, $39$

It happens to the best of us: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/57_(number)#In_mathematics

Note that this is irrational because there are arbitrarily long gaps between consecutive primes (e.g., n!+2 to n!+n are all composite).

This is A051006 on OEIS.
I don't think there is a known closed-form expression for this.
The OEIS entry does link some other material that may be interested, e.g. this.

What do you mean?
